# How to add events to move to other page for a dynamically created listview in jquery mobile?

Tags: json, html, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-templates

using the below code, I have inserted the data in the listview

```
var renderItemElement = function(item) {

    return $.tmpl("<li><a>${text}</a></li>", item)
        .data("item", item)
        .insertAfter(listHeaders[item.priority]);   
};
```

and when click it, i can remove the data, but when i click it, i want the data to be passed to the next page. Can anyone help me with this code?

```
$("#bankList").delegate("li.item", "click", function() {
   model.remove($(this).data("item"));
    $(this).slideUp(function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your  has a href or if you want the whole thing to display as a listview at all, you need to use `.listview()` method. If the ul tag already existed and is a listview, use `.listview('refresh')`

to move to another page with javascript, not a href, you need to use

`$.mobile.changePage()`